# How to Change the toolbar black color text into White in Xamarin.Android while retaining black text of activity text?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I create a toolbar in xamarin.android using this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

But text color shown is black but i want it to be white. My friend ask me to do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" 

app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

But it is showing following errors.

```
"No resource identifier found for attribute "theme" in package "android-auto"
"no resource identifier found for attribute "popupTheme" in package "android-auto"
```

Can you suggest some code.

Answer (score 1):

Think you are using the wrong package `app:` instead of `android:` in this bit

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com//apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light" />
```

Comment: Ah so did changing it to local:theme and local:popupTheme fix your issue?